# Полиморфизм в руби

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте - я новенький в руби и хотелось бы уточнить, что в Руби понимают под полиморфизмом.

Я понимаю, что на вопрос в интернете много статей но:

Когда я пришел на собеседование - и меня спросили что же такое полиморфизм.

Я ответил что: Это "как бы улучшенное наследование" - Класс-потомок наследуясь от класса-родителя перенимает у него все методы и может их переопределить, так же есть ключевое слово Super которое выполняет обратное наследование ( вызывает одноименный метод родительского класса )

Меня сказали, что это не верно 
Я еще только учусь - но думал что полиморфизм я понимаю верно - и тут возник вопрос - где я ошибся и как надо было отвечать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О полиморфизме можно узнать не мало, почитав **[статью на википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%EE%EB%E8%EC%EE%F0%F4%E8%E7%EC_(%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5))**. Этого будет достаточно, чтобы уловить его суть.

Полиморфизм - это свойство объектов с одинаковой спецификацией иметь различную реализацию. Как уже правильно был приведен пример из реальной жизни: есть тип транспорта - автомобиль и марки автомобилей - полиморфные объекты. Так, например, само по себе понятие "автомобиль" абстрактно, а вот если уже говорить о конкретной марке, то абстрактность исчезает. Это будет хорошо заметно, если взять "Запорожец" и "Роллс-Ройс". Эти объекты(марки) сильно отличаются друг от друга, но тем не менее оба они являются наследниками абстрактного понятия "автомобиль". Кардинальные отличия двум этим маркам придал именно полиморфизм. Как-то так =)

Answer (score 1):

Если в двух словах, то суть полиморфизма в следующем

Одна сущность - несколько реализаций.

Примеры из жизни: автомобиль, но несколько разных марок; собака, но несколько пород; и т.д.

Вот так и в программировании, объект может вести себя *полиморфно*, т.е. иметь разное поведение.

З.Ы. кажется я не могу объяснить что такое полиморфизм =\

Answer (score 1):

Под "полиморфизмом" в ООП языках обычно понимают возможность реализации различного поведения одноименных методов разных классов-потомков некого общего базового класса путем их переопределения(перекрытие метода) или доопределения(расширение метода или изменения поведения) в соответствующих классах-потомках.

При этом, если Вы строите некий алгоритм вокруг базового класса и набора его методов - то при следовании принципам ООП, аргументами передаваемыми в Ваш алгоритм могут быть экземпляры классов производных от базового(его потомков), так как например треугольник, квадрат и звезда - многоугольники, и у всех них есть некие общие базовые методы которые определены в базовом классе. При этом метод "нарисовать" будет рисовать разные фигуры, так как он доопределен или переопределен в классах потомках, но алгоритму этого знать не нужно. Важно то, что есть такой метод и его можно вызвать. Например от класса "звезда" Вы можете породить класс "звезда с цветочком". В методе "нарисовать" Вы в начале вызовите через super код предка(который нарисует звезду) а затем дорисуете цветочек, а не будете рисовать всю фигуру с нуля.
Это в первом приближении и есть "полиморфизм поведения".

Есть и другие формы полиморфизма, например полиморфизм параметров,
когда существует несколько разных реализаций метода с одним названием но разным объявленным набором параметров, и при вызове "на лету" принимается решение какая из этих реализаций должна быть вызвана в зависимости от того какие именно параметры были переданы, но это отдельная большая тема и в Руби такого механизма увы нету.

P.S.
Что именно "не понравится" экзаменаторам на собеседовании - можно почитать на других ресурсах где учат "как проходить собеседования"(это отдельная специальная дисциплина), но Ваш ответ был действительно не вполне строг с "научной точки зрения", и вероятнее всего кадровик проводивший собеседование ожидал именно сухого ответа из учебника по информатике в "научно-академическом стиле" с кучей "умных слов".
Кроме того, super является не "обратным наследованием", а ключевым словом языка Ruby означающим буквально: "вызови метод предка, с таким же именем(и если не указаны параметры - с тем же набором параметров) что у текущего метода". При этом это справедливо как для методов класса, так и для методов экземпляра класса. Просто в первом случае будет вызван метод класса класса-предка, а во втором - метод экземпляра класса-предка.

Answer (score 0):

Я не большой специалист в ООП (поэтому в терминологии могу ошибаться), но IMHO по сути Вы сказали правильно. Может быть фразу "улучшенное наследование" употреблять не следовало.

Естественно, переопределяя метод базового класса в производных от него классах мы тем самым меняем поведение метода (а значит и всего класса) с тем же именем в разных производных классах.

Соответственно, если есть ссылка на объект базового класса, а реально она ссылается на объект производного, то для данного объекта будет вызван метод производного класса.

Для вызова переопределенного метода базового класса в подобной ситуации надо использовать super.

Думаю, такое "словоблудие" удовлетворило бы экзаменаторов.

Comment: А вот что мне в ООП подходе реально **не нравится**, так это куча наукообразных слов на тему "масло масляное" и минимум конкретики в плане реализации.